# Webserver for Standalone Application on OSX

Tags: macos, web-applications, web

I'm developing an application used for analysis of large data set (audio files, pattern matching, etc.). The software must run out-of-the-box as a standalone application, i.e., without any internet connection. It is certainly doable in Java.

However, a web front-end would make our lives much easier since we have to display lots of structured tables containing graphics. This is very easy to achieve using html. Also, html is a lot more flexible than a JAVA GUI-components, i.e., allows for later adaption. Furthermore, for in-house usage, we could run the software as a normal web application on server hardware -- the software is thus more scalable. Hence, I was thinking about writing a web application.

Now, I know that certain web frameworks come with standalone webservers integrated. For instance, django has such a webserver integrated for development/testing purposes. However, it is not multi-threaded.

Do you know any standalone webservers (running on OSX) that fit my use case? They should run out-of-the-box listen on localhost and provide wsgi/fcgi.

How difficult is it to bundle, e.g., a preconfigured Apache? What about maintenance issues?

Many thanks in advance for your thoughts on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OS X comes with Apache [out of the box](http://osxdaily.com/2012/09/02/start-apache-web-server-mac-os-x/).  It's just a matter of configuring it.

Another choice is Ruby on Rails, which is easy to install on OS X since Ruby also comes preinstalled.